# Centering siunitx columns

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment, siunitx

I have the following table, with the decimal aligning handled by `siunitx` (MWE):

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        decimalsymbol=comma,
        locale = DE,
        }   \usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format = 2.8]S[table-format = 2.8]}
\toprule
& Parameter & {Estimate} & {Standard Error} \\
\midrule
EUR/USD model & $\hat \sigma_{X}$ & 0,0315 \\
[\defaultaddspace]
\multirow{4}{*}{GBP/USD model} & $\hat \omega$ & 0,000050 & 0,000045 \\ 
& $\hat \alpha_{Y}$ & 0,0860 & 0,0454 \\
& $\hat \beta_{Y}$ & 0,8585 & 0,0838 \\
& $\hat \nu$ & 7,6367 & 2,4094 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gives me:

[image: table]

What I would like is for the entries in the "Estimate" and "Standard Error" columns to be centered under the column titles (with the decimals still aligned properly). I suspect that I have to change the `table-format` but I haven't been able to figure out the right options.

Thanks!

Comment: `ccS[table-format = 1.6]S[table-format = 1.6]` 1 for integers and 6 for decimals.

Comment: `table-format = 1.6` doesn't seem to change anything for me, i. e. the columns and column headers are still not aligned properly.

Comment: does the picture of Svend and me does look aligned for you? If not, take a closer look on the second row, which is perfectly aligned. If you still don't like it, get rid of the last zero and change to `1.5` or leave it and change to `2.6` or `3.6` which moves everything more to the right. But I wouldn't do that.

Comment: Basically your columns look wrong because of the `2.8` which should be `1.6` to accommodate the actual data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the *decimal marker* placed at the center of the column -- and generate lots of wasted whitespace to the left of the leading digit -- then specify a symmetric `table-format` option, e.g., `table-format = 6.6`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%%\usepackage{multirow} % not needed
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        %%decimalsymbol=comma, %% not needed, as implied by `locale=DE` option
        locale = DE,
        }  
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} cc *{2}{S[table-format = 6.6]} @{}}
\toprule
& Parameter & {Estimate} & {Std.\ Error} \\
\midrule
EUR/USD model & $\hat \sigma_{X}$ & 0,0315 \\
[\defaultaddspace]
GBP/USD model & $\hat \omega$ & 0,000050 & 0,000045 \\ 
& $\hat \alpha_{Y}$ & 0,0860 & 0,0454 \\
& $\hat \beta_{Y}$ & 0,8585 & 0,0838 \\
& $\hat \nu$ & 7,6367 & 2,4094 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

I think the table looks *much better* if you set `table-format = 1.6`:

[image]

Comment: That's what I was after but now that I see it, I think you are right. It looks much better with the `table-format = 1.6` as has been suggested by you and the other users. Thank!

Comment: The decimal points should be changed to `.`. Otherwise there is no point in invoking `decimalsymbol=comma`.

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - Thanks for this. I've commented out the `decimalsymbol=comma` option as it's implied by the `locale=DE` option. (If you comment out `locale=DE`, though, `siunitx` will generate `.` as the output decimal marker.)

Answer (score 5):

You have at most 1 digit before the decimal marker and 6 after it. Therefore, you should do as follows to get the desired output:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[
  decimalsymbol = comma,
  group-digits = false
]{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
 \centering
  \begin{tabular}{l c *{2}{S[table-format = 1.6]}
  }
   \toprule
                                   & Parameter        & {Estimate} & {Standard Error} \\
   \midrule
    EUR/USD model                  & $\hat\sigma_{X}$ & 0.0315                        \\[1ex]
    \multirow{4}{*}{GBP/USD model} & $\hat\omega$     & 0.000050   & 0.000045         \\ 
                                   & $\hat\alpha_{Y}$ & 0.0860     & 0.0454           \\
                                   & $\hat\beta_{Y}$  & 0.8585     & 0.0838           \\
                                   & $\hat\nu$        & 7.6367     & 2.4094           \\
   \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it still doesn't look centered to me the way the "Parameter" column and the greek letters are.

Comment: @user2249626 Well, they are centered. `:)`

Comment: Perhaps the OP should add (temporary) vertical lines to realize that the columns are *centered*

Comment: I think I didn't ask my question very well. What I meant by centered is something like this (screenshot taken from the `siunitx`documentation): https://www.dropbox.com/s/fvb5avxesnhn96b/Screenshot%202014-06-06%2016.42.20.png

Comment: @user2249626 This is exactly how it is. The numbers are both aligned and vertically centered (relative to the longest string of digits before and after the decimal marker).

Comment: @user2249626 - do you want the *decimal marker* centered in the column (and have lots of whitespace to the left)?

Comment: @Mico Yes I think that's what I mean. I'm not sure it's a good idea (I'd have to see how it looks on the actual page) but yes, I think that's what I was asking.

Comment: @user2249626 That definitely doesn't look good at all. Trust me. `:)`

Comment: @SvendTveskæg - For the record, I did upvote your answer...

Answer (score 3):

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{%
        detect-mode,
        group-digits            = false,
        input-symbols           = ( ) [ ] - +,
        table-align-text-post   = false,
        input-signs             = ,
        output-decimal-marker   =comma,
        locale                  = DE,
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ccS[table-format = 1.6]S[table-format = 1.6]}
\toprule
& Parameter & {Estimate} & {Standard Error} \\
\cmidrule(){2-4}
EUR/USD model & $\hat \sigma_{X}$ & 0,0315 \\
[\defaultaddspace]
\multirow{4}{*}{GBP/USD model} & $\hat \omega_{\phantom{Y}}$ & 0,000050 & 0,000045 \\ 
& $\hat \alpha_Y$ & 0,0860 & 0,0454 \\
& $\hat \beta_Y$ & 0,8585 & 0,0838 \\
& $\hat \nu_{\phantom{Y}}$ & 7,6367 & 2,4094 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]